# Watch 7 Qwerty keyboard is not shown in the App

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I am trying to use Apple Watch 7 qwerty keyboard in simulator for my app but the keyboard is not showing in the app.

- Qwerty keyboard not supported in simulator?
- As developers, can't we use the qwerty keyboard in our applications?

Any suggestions?

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Watch 7 does support qwerty keyboard in simulator.

After click on TextField, you get prompted Scribble.

[image: Scribble view]

Then you click on the arrow at the bottom of the screen, under space, and drag it to the top. You get prompted the Keyboard selector.

[image: Keyboard selector]

Now you select the Keyboard one.

[image: Qwerty keyboard]

There you go! Hope that's what you need!